# Framer Motion: Shared layout animations stop working when motion.div grandparent changes flex-direction

Tags: framer-motion

I'm trying to replicate [this effect where the active tab indicator is animated](https://www.framer.com/motion/examples/#shared-layout-animations).

My [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/vietan0/fm-e-commerce-product-page/main?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clshmszql00062a66f0liie1s%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clshmszql00022a66mhsrg4mx%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clshmszql00042a660leezu4k%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clshmszql00052a66zq3byyp3%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B51.442126171284755%252C48.557873828715245%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clshmszql00022a66mhsrg4mx%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clshmszql00022a66mhsrg4mx%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clshn74yp00hp2a66r9pk0j5f%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252F.codesandbox%252Ftasks.json%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clshn74yp00hp2a66r9pk0j5f%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clshmszql00052a66zq3byyp3%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clshmszql00052a66zq3byyp3%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clshn6hup00aq2a66ut8ehkw1%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clshn6hup00aq2a66ut8ehkw1%2522%257D%252C%2522clshmszql00042a660leezu4k%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clshmszql00042a660leezu4k%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clshmt1lf00612a66gkhmht8k%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clshmt1lf00612a66gkhmht8k%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A0%257D)

Expected behavior: The navlink's highlight should be animated regardless of the flex container's direction.

Current behavior: It only animates when `flex-direction` is `column`, not `row`.

Line 25: Here's the orange highlight:

```js
{hoverAnchor === link && (
  <motion.div
    layoutId="underline"
    transition={{ duration: 0.15 }}
    className="absolute bottom-0 left-0 h-[2px] w-full bg-orange"
  />
)}
```

Line 58: Here's the `<motion.ul>` grandparent, which is a flexbox: column when screen size <= 640px, otherwise row:

```js
<motion.ul
  initial={{ x: 'var(--menu-offscreen)' }}
  animate={{ x: menuOpen ? 0 : 'var(--menu-offscreen)' }}
  onMouseLeave={() => setHoverAnchor('')}
  className="fixed left-4 top-4 flex h-[calc(100vh_-_2rem)] w-[calc(100vw_-_2rem)] flex-col rounded-lg bg-white py-4 [--menu-offscreen:-400px] xs:max-w-[368px] sm:static sm:h-auto sm:w-auto sm:max-w-full sm:flex-row sm:py-0 sm:outline-none sm:[--menu-offscreen:0px]"
>
```

It will animate correctly if `flex-direction` is `column`

It will animate correctly if I turn the grandparent `<motion.ul>` back into a regular `<ul>`, but I don't want to because it has its own animation to do.

Not sure what I'm missing, and the docs doesn't seem to say anything about nesting motion divs, or I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tinkered around and found the problem lies in the CSS variables, not `<motion.ul>` itself:

```js
<motion.ul
  initial={{ x: 'var(--menu-offscreen)' }}
  animate={{ x: menuOpen ? 0 : 'var(--menu-offscreen)' }}
  className="[--menu-offscreen:-400px] sm:[--menu-offscreen:0px]"
>
```

I was trying to animate `x` based on CSS variable `--menu-offscreen` which changes depending on Tailwind's breakpoints. The problem disappears if I don't use `var(--menu-offscreen)` in `intial` and `animate`, so I replace it with a fixed number, and now I handle the breakpoint changes with React instead of Tailwind. It looks something like this:

```js
{/* react state */ smallScreen && (
  <motion.ul
    initial={{ x: -400 }}
    animate={{ x: 0 }}
  />
)}
```